# Splash | Loading screen (with timeout) before website load (portfolio)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm writing my own portfolio website in NextJS and I'd like to have short (like... 3s or 5s max) splash screen before first load/visit of the user and display it only once per user's visit. Could any1 give me some suggestions? :) I can provide some screenshots/code if needed.

Good example is here - https://p5aholic.me/ (eventually if that wouldn't be too hard It could display also on website refresh)

My _app.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Top from '../components/top'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Top />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it to the user on first visit only, maybe you could store it in localstorage?
when the page loads check in localstorage for a boolean value, then if the variable is undefined use setTimeout function to render the splash screen for a few seconds. Remember to update the value in localstorage to a value you can check for afterwards when the user visits again.